# Cannot Edit Features of PostGIS Layers in OpenGeo GeoExplorer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geoext, boundless-suite, wfs-t

I admit I  originally posted the question here:
http://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/cannot_edit_features_of_postgis_layers

But due to no response and not finding a solution, I thought I'd try to ask here.

I have imported some layers from my PostGIS DB into the OpenGeo Suite Geoserver. For the most part they work fine, yet I am unable to edit their features. Every time I try to do this I get the following in FireBug:

feature is undefined
layer.drawFeature(feature,feature.styl...stFeature=layer.selectedFeatures[0];}
OpenLayers.js (line 815)

However, if I import a layer that came bundled with the suite such as World - Borders, everything works fine and I am able to do feature editing as expected. I have also seen this thread:

http://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/to...

But still I am not sure how to go about it. It is indeed true that we had PostgreSQL and PostGIS installed already, and when I installed the OpenGeo suite all the data dumped itself onto my already existing PostGIS (at least I think so), as everything seems to be running on the same port 5432. What can I do to have my PostGIS layers allow feature editing? This was the main reason we decided to go with GeoExplorer ;).

Geoserver error logs report:

```
INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
handle = null
service = WFS
version = 1.1.0
baseUrl = http://10.0.104.14:8081/geoserver/
providedVersion = null
extendedProperties = {}
query = [net.opengis.wfs.impl.QueryTypeImpl@431e34c7 (group: null, propertyName: null, function: null, filter: [ tib_villages.fid-5a164ff3_134c8d54c27_-6fb2 ], sortBy: null, featureVersion: null, handle: null, srsName: EPSG:900913, typeName: [{http://opengeo.org/#tibet}tib_villages])]
maxFeatures = 20
outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
resultType = results
traverseXlinkDepth = null
traverseXlinkExpiry = null
formatOptions = {}
metadata = null
```

Thanks for your time and I am looking forward to hearing any feedback,

elshae